# how to get image of scanned barcode in vision libarary android

Tags: android, google-play-services, qr-code, android-vision

I successfully implemented vision library by Google sample and it successfully scanned bar codes and returns a string. I also want bar-code image so my question is how to get image of bar-code or a preview image?

Note: Code is based on git hub sample of google vision library.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide some code and show us what you have tried so far

Comment: You can get the image using [BitmapFactory.decodeResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) which returns the bitmap. Example: `Bitmap myBitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),R.drawable.qrcode);`. You can find it in this [tutorial](http://arjunu.com/2015/08/android-barcode-detection-tracking-using-mobile-vision-api/).

Comment: R.drawable.q‌​rcode is applicable when there is a image in drawable . we scan qrcode from camera and it returns only string . so this method is not use in my code .

and here is the code which im used to scan qr https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader

Comment: @Mayank Sharma
Have You got anything?

I am looking for the same!

Comment: yes 
i had got the solution but there is full view of image means only barcode is not possible
you can extract full image from camera class